# First time creating an app for Android and IOS

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

I'm trying to create an app for Andriod and IOS, but i have no clue how to do the front-end and have a hard time deciding to use HTML5, CSS & JS or Objective objective C/Java.

I'ts going to be use network options, checkout-features, joined checkout-features. Maps api, facebook api.

I've got expierence in HTML5, CSS3, SASS, PHP and JS.

I've tried looking online, but i've still got no clue how to do the front-end for app.

Comment: This kind of open-ended question that leads to extended discussions is not appropriate to Stack Overflow. Narrowly-defined laser-focused technical problems are on-topic here. Please look for the "help" button or link to learn how to use Stack Overflow properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you will use framework like [phonegrap](http://phonegap.com), [Titanium Appcelarator](http://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/) and I guess you can use [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/),  Ionic, Framework7 as well. For Titanium, you have to use different environment for different app (OSX for iOS products and OsX, Windows or Linux distros to run android app) and have it's own syntax and everything. Language is one of Javascript versions (I am guessing, I have used it once 2 years ago). And Phonegap and other Frameworks use a varient of JS, so basically you will have to use HTML and CSS to work with UI. However, you will face some hardware constraint like unable to access hardware buttons (from my experience with one project some months ago) and memory management and other functionalities will mostly depend on your JS coding skill.

[My opinion] I believe, the best way to develop an app is to develop in its native language/framework. I believe it. Unless you're bound to use Html, JS to build app (you can!), don't use those. Java is there to help you with Android Development, since I am an developer, I can tell you that starting might seem a bit difficult than iOS development. But in the end, communities like stackOverFlow and thousands of thousands blogs will help you. Same case for iOS app development. You can find lots of different tutorials. [New Bostons](https://thenewboston.com/) tutorial helped with android however, it's contents are bit old (android 2.3) and mostly everything has changed since. However, you can check his iOS app development with Swift. Learning a new language is mostly like learning how to ride bicycle. If you can know how to ride, keep learning the advance parts after basic mechanics, you can become a pro one day. However, for that you have to pass a whole cartoon of hurdles (unknown bugs, sleepless nights to name a few) like the falls you did when learning how to ride. 
I would really suggest you to focus on building a real stack.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's a hard decision, but if i understand it correctly, native can be optimized better for the platform, while the other us more unstable, but easier to create.. I'm heavily weighing out my options, but your answer and those of the others have definitely made it easier.

Comment: @Notorious_Creed, you are correct about the native parts. Glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

For android:
I would recommend using Android Studio. 
It is a powerful tool for creating an android app - the front end can be implemented by dragging and dropping items or by using xml.
It is easy to use and there a lot of tutorials online.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an iOS developer on the native side. If you want to do native development, I would recommend Stanford course CS193P by Paul Hegarty. You can find this course on iTunes U, Coursera and other MOOC platforms. For advanced features, follow a GitHub repo called "awesome-ios" where you'll learn some production level stuff for iOS apps. If you want to do hybrid apps, have a look at PhoneGap, Ionic, React.

In either case, you would be able to implement features you've described in your question.

Tools needed for Native Development: a machine which runs macOS and Xcode(free download from app store).

Comment: CS193P, is this course available as non-paid version in iTunes?

Comment: Yes! You can find them as "Developing iOS 9 apps with swift". Make sure you are viewing the Stanford one. There are also older versions till iOS 7 if you want to learn using Objective-C. The main thing I would recommend to you is getting familiar with Cocoa Touch framework. Choosing a programming language shouldn't be a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

I started developing native apps years ago. The last 2 years I've been using only hybrid possibilities. Designing and developing an app in HTML / CSS / JS is much easier and more efficiently.

I recommend taking a look at Phonegap, Ionic, Framework7. These are open source and there are already some templates.